# Solution to collect in ruby modifying original data?

Tags: ruby, collections, dictionary

I have some simple code here where I'm taking data from a hash and pushing into an array and using a collect call to modify the array. However, at the end of the program my original hash is being modified. I understand Ruby works with references but I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

```
hash = Hash.new
hash ={"a" => "2.3M", "b" => "1.2B"}

revenue = []

revenue << hash["a"]
revenue << hash["b"]

revenue.collect! do |rev|
    if rev.include? "B"
        rev = rev.gsub!("B","").to_f * 1000000000
    elsif rev.include? "M"
        rev = rev.gsub!("M","").to_f * 1000000
    else
        rev = rev
    end
end

p revenue # => [2300000.0, 1200000000.0]
p hash # => {"a"=>"2.3", "b"=>"1.2"} Why do the M and B dissapear?
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave out the `!` in `gsub!`. That way `gsub` will make a copy of the string before modifying it.